# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist."

Tags: swift, linux, telegram-bot, vapor

I'm creating a Telegram bot on swift and vapor.

Created logFile.txt to store responses and outputs from people. The code works on mac. But when I build a project on Linux, I get this error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist."

```
//MARK:- Extension for String
extension String {
    func appendLineToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
         try (self + "\n").appendToURL(fileURL: fileURL)
     }

     func appendToURL(fileURL: URL) throws {
         let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
         try data.append(fileURL: fileURL)
     }
 }
//MARK:- Extension for File data
extension Data {
    func append(fileURL: URL) throws {
        if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {
            defer {
                fileHandle.closeFile()
            }
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(self)
        }
        else {
            try write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        }
    }
}
```

## **Main body:**

```
 if update.message?.text != nil {
               
                do {
                    let dir: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as URL
                     let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("/logFile.txt")
                    
                    try "\(format.string(from: date)); litl nis bot:   \(update.message?.text ?? "Error")".appendLineToURL(fileURL: url.standardized as URL)
        
                 }
                 catch {
                     print("Something went wrong:  \(error)")
                 }
```

Wanna create file in Linux with logs and ability to open it )

May be there is some problems with intermediate directories itself ?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall encountering this problem when I first deployed to Linux after development on macOS. I solved it using this function that works on both:

```swift
func workingDirectoryURL(with components: [String] = []) throws -> URL {
    let workPath = DirectoryConfiguration.detect().workingDirectory
    if workPath == "" { throw InternalError.misc() }
    var workPathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: workPath)
    components.forEach { component in workPathURL = workPathURL.appendingPathComponent(component) }
    return workPathURL
}
```

You can then call it with something like:

```swift
workingDirectoryURL(with: ["path","relative","to","project","directory","logFile.txt"])
```

If you are looking simply to log events though, I would recommend looking at vapor's logging here: https://docs.vapor.codes/basics/logging/?h=log